# Filtering GeoJSON with JQ

Tags: javascript, json, filter, geojson, jq

Given this JSON

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "MODE": "A"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -69.23583984375,
          45.460130637921004
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "MODE": "D"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -69.23651039600372,
          45.46053888199693
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter through and select the `features` that possess the `MODE: D` property.  As far as I can tell, the query `jq .[] | select(.MODE == "D")` should work, but it doesn't!

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jq ' .. | select( has("properties") )? | select( .properties.MODE == "D")'`

The question mark tells jq to ignore errors. The .. is to recurse into the object

`jq '.features[] | select(.properties.MODE == "D")'`

Will get you the results you are after without recursion just to note the differences in the methods

for reference: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/610

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quite a lot.  You used `.[]` but what is that supposed to accomplish?  The `MODE` is a property of the `properties` object of a feature.

```
.features | map(select(.properties.MODE == "D"))
```